# How to get the head and rest of an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array and would like to get its head and the rest. How do I do this using a destructuring assignment? Is this even possible?

If the array has only two elements, it's pretty easy:

```
const [head, rest] = myArray;
```

But what if it contains more than two entries?

Comment: use spread syntax `const [head, ...rest] = myArray;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for that.

```
const [head, ...rest] = myArray;
```

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const [head, ...rest] = myArray;

console.log(head);
console.log(rest);
```

Comment: Although the other answers are correct as well, this was the first one. Hence I accepted this one as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thay way:

```
const [head, ...rest] = myArray;
```

Answer (score 2):

With the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), all other items goes into the rest array.

```js
const [head, ...rest] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(head);
console.log(rest);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```js
const [car, ...cdr] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(car); // 1

console.log(cdr); // [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

For more details, refer this [link](http://raganwald.com/2015/02/02/destructuring.html)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to Destructing assignment (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) :

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var [y, z] = x;

console.log(y); // 1
console.log(z); // 2
```